# Input TYPE TEXT Value from JSP form (enctype="multipart/form-data") returns null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, multipartform-data

I need to upload an image:

```
<form method="post" action="hi.iq/register.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="J.Doe">
    file: <input type="file" name="file-upload">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In my servlet I gave

```
response.setContentType("text/html");

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    

String name = request.getParameter("name");

System.out.println("user_id========= "+name);
```

but the value of `name` is returned as `NULL`.

Pls Help

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="J.Doe">`.

Edit:

A sample using Apache Commons Fileupload, as suggested by David's answer:

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Set factory constraints
// factory.setSizeThreshold(yourMaxMemorySize);
// factory.setRepository(yourTempDirectory);

// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload( factory );
// upload.setSizeMax(yourMaxRequestSize);

// Parse the request
List<FileItem> uploadItems = upload.parseRequest( request );

for( FileItem uploadItem : uploadItems )
{
  if( uploadItem.isFormField() )
  {
    String fieldName = uploadItem.getFieldName();
    String value = uploadItem.getString();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but still the value is NULL

Comment: I'm just voting your post up and down to see the unicorns.

Comment: @jennifer, did you get any solution for it. I am also getting the value null when I try to use request.getParameter("name"). If you have any solution for it, please let me know?

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
     FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
     ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
     Iterator<FileItem> iterator = upload.parseRequest(request).iterator();
     File uploadedFile;
     String dirPath="D:\fileuploads";
     while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                    FileItem item = iterator.next();
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {

                        String fileNameWithExt = item.getName();

                        File filePath = new File(dirPath);

                        if (!filePath.exists()) {
                            filePath.mkdirs();
                        }

                        uploadedFile = new File(dirPath + "/" + fileNameWithExt);
                        item.write(uploadedFile);                  
                    }
                    else {
            String otherFieldName = item.getFieldName();
            String otherFieldValue = item.getString()
                    }
               }
```

It needs Apache `commons-fileupload.jar` and `commons-io.jar`

Answer (score 5):

No container that I have used supports multipart encoded requests out of the box. Due to this, it cannot parse parameters and you cannot use request.getParameter() out of the box.

You need to use something on the server side like [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) to preprocess the request

Comment: You're right, didn't see the multipart declaration. I'll add a sample of our code in my answer.

Comment: So you have never used the since Dec-2009 released Servlet 3.0 API?

Answer (score 1):

The `null` value returned by the `request.getParameter("name");` is due to the fact that you are using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html form.

This has been thoroughly answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/1148972).

Answer (score 0):

Add Annotaion   **@javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig**  and then just simply use request.getParameter() it will work Perfectly.

Or If you are using MultipartFormDataRequest then use its object Like MultipartFormDataRequest mrequest;
in place of request for ex. mrequest.getParameter("name"); It works.