# multipart/form-data not working with servlets

Tags: java, html, jsp, upload

I am not really sure why the html form with the tag enctype="multipart/form-data" does not pass the objects it should pass. this is the case with mozilla and firefox.

for IEs case, for example, I use html control to choose a file, it does get what it is supposed to get.

Now I just want to know if there are any alternatives I can use to pass in files through http request object because the enctype="multipart/form-data" seems to be having some compatibility issues but I am not really sure

any suggestions would be appreciated! :D

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512442/input-type-text-value-from-jsp-form-enctype-multipart-form-data-returns-nul

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Comment: And please also read [How to get file path in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3/3374408#3374408)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it. if someone else might have a problem like this, this was my problem. i checked the content type of the file for me to ensure that the objects passed is of a certain type. in IE, it returns application/x-zip-compressed THAT IS ONLY FOR IE but mozilla and chrome seems to be returning a different content type for the zip file which is application/octet-stream.

so i just added the application/octet-stream to the valid filetypes and it seems to be working now

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you have to provide a little bit of code to show what you have done, and to know what went wrong. Anyway, I am assuming that you have to upload a file to the server using HTML file upload control.

File upload or to say `multipart/form-data` encoding type support is not implemented in `HttpServlet` implementation. So, the `request.getParameter()` don't work with  `multipart/form-data`. You have to use additional libraries which provide support for this. [Apache Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) is a good example. Their [using fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) guide will help you to get started with the library. Here is a simple example (compiled from using file upload guide).

```
// Check that we have a file upload request
boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

if (isMultipart) {
    // Create a factory for disk-based file items
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

    // Create a new file upload handler
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    // Parse the request
    List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(request);

    // Process the uploaded items
    Iterator iter = items.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

        if (item.isFormField()) {
            // Process form field.
            String name = item.getFieldName();
            String value = item.getString();
        } else {
            // Process uploaded file.
            String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
            String fileName = item.getName();
            String contentType = item.getContentType();
            boolean isInMemory = item.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = item.getSize();

            if (writeToFile) {
                File uploadedFile = new File("path/filename.txt");
                item.write(uploadedFile);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    // Normal request. request.getParameter will suffice.
}
```